# Ag grid react warning: State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback argument

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I tried to make an app as simple as possible to make the error easier to understand so I just implemented it in the App.tsx.

```
import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react";
...

function App() {
// I know these should be states or memos, but I wanted to be sure it was not that the problem, it happens // exactly the same using useState or useMemo
  const rowData = [
    {make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000},
    {make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000},
    {make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000}
  ];
  const columnDefs = [
    {field: 'make'},
    {field: 'model'},
  ];


  return (
    <>
      <AgGridReact rowData={rowData} columnDefs={columnDefs} />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Only this code is giving me these warnings:
[image: Multiple warnings]

Using the prop suppressReactUi does not throw these warnings, but it is legacy code, as noticed by another warning from aggrid.

What am I doing wrong? This happened after updating from version 19 and I thought it was something we were doing, thats the reason I tried to Isolate the problem in app.tsx.

First I tried changing the functions we were passing to the AgGridReact component but it was pointless.

Update: I debugged a bit and realised it is something related to the scroll:
[image]

So it could probably be happening because of these hooks:
[image]

Or these ones:
[image]

Comment: Seems to be working fine in AG Grid v27.1.0: https://plnkr.co/edit/rc6Q2MGDyoyUZX9f 

Please provide a repro showing your issue.

Comment: I honestly do not know how to reproduce it. It is only happening in my work environment so Its not easy to show it. Do you have any Idea what could be producing it? I am using that version too.

Comment: The error is still happening. I tried to replicate this but it was not possible, it only happens in our work environment. We noticed it only jappens in gridcomp and it must be related to ReactUI (since disabling it removes the warning). I updated the post because it looks it is something related to the scrolling.

Comment: I get the same warnings in storybook. These warnings weren't there in v26 of ag-grid-react